# RequiredFieldValidator blocks the bootstrap modal pop up

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-modal, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a button

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary horizontal-bar" id="btnAdd" runat="server" onserverclick="btnAdd_ServerClick">
            Add
        </button>
```

which calls the method

```
  protected void btnAdd_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "script", "<script type='text/javascript'>$( document ).ready(function() { $('#GaragesModal').modal('show')});</script>", false);
    }
```

which should open up the modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="GaragesModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog small">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Garages</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">                             
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtName_TextChanged" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z ]*$" ErrorMessage="Name required" ForeColor="#ff0000" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="errormessage" ControlToValidate="txtName" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                    </div>...(closing tags)
```

The issue is when I add **asp:RequiredFieldValidator** to the textbox like shown in the code, the method **btnAdd_ServerClick** is not fired when clicking the button. **asp:RegularExpressionValidator** works fine. Any idea why it is and any other way of validating required field. Thank you in advance.

Comment: which type of button is that `<button>` ?

Comment: try using asp:button and add causevalidation for the button and check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hookup the validators in modal popup with only the button in modal popup and right now the validators are hooked up with `Add` button also. You can do this by assigning a `ValidationGroup` for the validators and the button in the modal popup. Don't provide any `ValidationGroup` for the `Add` button since it only opens the popup.

You have not shown a button in modal popup but I am sure you have one. Please set the `ValidationGroup` of that button to the same value as for the validators.

Don't give any validation group to `Add` button and set its `CausesValidation` property to false.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName"
   ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z ]*$" ErrorMessage="Name required"
   ForeColor="#ff0000" ValidationGroup="Save"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="errormessage" 
  ControlToValidate="txtName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Save"/>
```

Comment: You are correct.It was the problem.Thank you.Saved my day :)

Comment: @Sunil; I am facing same issue. I have added validation group to all validators and button, still modal won't open ! My button which trying to open modal is inside a gridview and update panel. If validators are removed, everything working fine... Any idea ?

Comment: @Milind Thakkar,  Remove validation group from the button that opens the popup,  and also set CausesValidation property of this button to false.  Try this and let me know.  If this doesn't work then post it as a new question.

Comment: @Sunil: Already tried that. No luck. I will revisit my code once again to see if can find solution, else will post new question. Let me know if you find any pointer in the meanwhile. Thanks !

Comment: I think you should post your code since there seems to be some other issue with your scenario.  What javascript is in click event of button?  Better if you post it.